# ask about Custom TableViewCell

Tags: uitableview

i wanna every cell to dynamically show different picture,how can i manage every cell to recognise the picture?I wanna the cell have different pictures,and the height of cell is defined by the picture's height

Answer (score 0):

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

Try the above code for adding images to your tableview cell.

Also this tutorial might help: 
http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/
Hope this helps Adrian